# Unable to delete record from associated table(Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table group_transactions in which user who belongs to a group(groups - table) stores the transactions between the members of that group. **What I am trying to achive is to delete records from group_transactions when admin deletes the user - if the id of the user being deleted matches the id in the issuer_id or borrower_id column**.
**The error I get when admin deletes user is:**
**SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: group_transactions.user_id**
It points at my destroy action in the UsersController.

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transactions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :relations
  has_many :group_transactions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

GroupTransaction model:

```
class GroupTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :issuer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "issuer_id"
  belongs_to :borrower, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "borrower_id"
  belongs_to :group  
end
```

UsersController(only the relevent actions):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :is_logged_in?, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  before_action :grant_access, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy  
    flash[:success] = "User has been deleted!"
    redirect_to users_path
  end 

  def index
    @users = User.all 
  end

  private

  def user_params 
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :nick, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end 

  def grant_access
    unless User.exists?(id: params[:id])
      flash[:danger] = "You cannot see that!"
      redirect_to root_url
    end 
  end 
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "group_transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "value"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "issuer_id"
    t.integer "borrower_id"
    t.index ["borrower_id"], name: "index_group_transactions_on_borrower_id"
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_group_transactions_on_group_id"
    t.index ["issuer_id"], name: "index_group_transactions_on_issuer_id"
  end
```

When I delete group all of the associated group transactions are deleted - it works as I want.
Moreover, everything works fine when I delete user who belongs to a group that does not have any group transactions(no errors). However, if there is a group transactions the following error occurs - **SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: group_transactions.user_id**.

I know that group_transactions does not have a "user_id".It has "issuer_id" and "borrower_id" which underneath points to users table.
Thanks for your help and advice,
Luk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is not working because the `dependent: :destroy` part of the User class searches by default the `group_transactions.user_id` field of the GroupTransactions table, but it doesn't exist (only `issuer_id` exists).

Try changing

```
  has_many :group_transactions, dependent: :destroy
```

to

```
  has_many :group_transactions, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :issuer_id
```

Comment: I've changed that, and now I get different error: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed.

Comment: @L.Wini I think this is the second foreign_key causing problems, both users must be destroyed for a group_transaction to be destroyed

Comment: Do you have an idea how to overcome this?I have been thinking about  before_destroy callback.

Comment: @L.Wini I think the best way to do it would be to remove 1 of the 2 foreign_key. You would have 1 foreign_key, the "master", and 1 normal field, the "slave". It would depend on which of the 2 is the most important. Rails doesn't need an explicit `foreign_key` statement, all it needs is the field name, so it should work properly.

Comment: But maybe there is a better way, that's just the way i would do it

Comment: So I followed your advice and it works now!To be honest, I do not know what I have put 2 foreign keys in group_transactions tabel. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to update association in `User` model

```
has_many :group_transactions, dependent: :destroy
```

To something like following

```
has_many :issuing_group_transactions, 
         class_name: "GroupTransaction", 
         foreign_key: "issuer_id", 
         dependent: :destroy
has_many :borrowing_group_transactions, 
         class_name: "GroupTransaction", 
         foreign_key: "borrower_id", 
         dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: I get the following error:ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in UsersController#destroy(top one) SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed